# Неверно выводятся посты в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Вывожу посты с помощью функции get_posts().
В файлах index.php и category.php такой код работает и выводит все записи, которые я создал в админке.
Но я захотел выводить 3 последних поста в sidebar с помощью созданного action в function.php add_action('last_posts', 'last_three_posts'); Это действие я вызываю в файле sidebar.php. Но проблема в том, что при вызове этого действия выводится данная страница, на которой вызывается, а не посты.
Если просто вставить этот код в sidebar.php, без действия, то все хорошо. Не могу понять, почему посты теряются в созданной функции в function.php.[image: Код в функции]

[image: Вызов в sidebar]

[image: Отображение на сайте]

[image: Написание кода напрямую]

[image: Правильное отображение]

Comment: Приводите примеры кода не скриншотами, а текстом

Answer (score 1):

Внутри `last_three_posts()` нужно сначала продекларировать `global $post;`. Иначе вы не замените глобальную переменную после выборки.

```
function last_three_posts() {

    global $post;

    // ...

}
```

Ознакомьтесь с [описанием](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) функции `setup_postdata()`

> setup_postdata() **does not assign the global $post variable** so it's important that you do this yourself. Failure to do so **will cause problems with any hooks that use any of the above globals in conjunction with the $post global**, as they will refer to separate entities.

Или на русском [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/setup_postdata):

> Функция **не устанавливает переменную $post как глобальную,** а ожидает,
>   что передаваемая переменная $post уже глобальная. Если функция
>   используется внутри цикла, то нужно передать текущий объект поста в
>   цикле.

По той же русскоязычной ссылке есть подробные примеры (№4, №5), описывающие в том числе и вашу проблему.

Вообще, для таких мелких вторичных выборок не обязательно создавать вторичный цикл с переопределением глобальных переменных. Вы можете просто получить желаемые посты функцией get_posts() и вывести ссылки с помощью функций `get_the_title()` и `get_permalink()`, передав им ID текущего поста в цикле:

```
$my_posts = get_posts ( $args );

// if ( ! empty( $my_posts ) ) :

foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):

    $my_link = get_permalink( $my_post->ID );
    $my_title = get_the_title( $my_post->ID );

    echo "<a href='$my_link'>$my_title</a><br />";

endforeach;

// endif;
```